# how to draw a horizontal line in 3 timeframes at the same time

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm trading using 3 time frames. I would like to draw a horizontal line at the price I bought in the lowest 15 sec time frame as well as draw a line for my stop in that time frame, but I would like to have both those line show up in the 2 higher timeframes. Is there a setting that would allow me to sync lines in all time frames, or do I need to code something like this, and if so how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that programmatically. Your script will run on one chart only.

You can achieve what you want to do if you draw the lines manually.

[image]